# Facebook manually login flow - not getting access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a desktop app.  A part of this app require the use of facebook to get some content from any profile.

Currently, in my app, via a (a popup), a user can login to facebook and authorize my desktop app to interact with it's profile.

After that, the user is redirected back, the access token appear correctly in the url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=BigTokenString&expires_in=5341.
```

But it appears only for few seconds and after that the url is replaced by [https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#_=_)

with a message success and a security message :

```
Success
SECURITY WARNING : Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.
```

If I'm understanding this correct i need the access_token to send back to facebook.

Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Comment: add login_success.html to your web root directory. After the callback, it expects to find that file, but redirects to blank.html because it could not find a login_success.html file

Answer (score 1):

Add login_success.html to your web root directory. After the callback, it expects to find that file, but redirects to blank.html because it could not find a login_success.html file

Add this code in the file.

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>
    window.opener.openFB.oauthCallback(window.location.href);
    window.close();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what do I have to place in this file?